# How to guard both '/login' or '/login/', and '/dashboard' or '/dashboard/' in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue-router to set routeguard in my system, redirecting the user if there's a token back to dashboard if they try to input /login or /login/ in the URL, and vice versa if they have no token.

**router.js**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.fullPath === '/dashboard/') {
    if (!store.state.authToken) {
      next('/login');
    }
  }
  if (to.fullPath === '/login/') {
    if (store.state.accessToken) {
      next('/dashboard');
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

my problem is that if I type '/login' or '/dashboard' (without the backslash in the end), it bypasses my guard, so I tried doing  `(to.fullPath === '/login/' || '/login')` and `(to.fullPath === '/dashboard/' || '/dashboard')` in my code, which was a success literally 4 hours ago.

Then I returned now and it's now giving me errors, saying `[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation` whenever I change views via URL.

I have no idea why it stopped working, please help.

Thank you!

EDIT: I made a typo and was calling accessToken instead of  authToken that's why the guard failed. Fixed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your routes a name and redirect based on that instead.

An extra change could be to add some meta to your routes whether the route requires the user to be authenticated, making it easier to scale without having to specify each protected route in your beforeEach

routes

```
{
  path: '/login',
  name: 'login',
  component: () => import('./views/Login.vue'),
  meta: { requiresAuth: false }
},
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  name: 'dashboard',
  component: () => import('./views/Dasboard.vue'),
  meta: { requiresAuth: true }
}
```

guard

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  /* Both '/login' and '/login/' should share the same route name even if their path is different */
  if (to.name === 'login') {
    if (store.state.accessToken) {
      next('/dashboard');
    }
  }

  //Redirect to login if the route requires auth and no token is set
  if(to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    if (!store.state.accessToken) {
      next('/login');
    }
  }

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `startsWith` instead of `===` for comparison:

```
if (to.fullPath.startsWith('/dashboard') {...
```

This way you're not concerned with the trailing slashes, etc.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you

Although now, it doesn't redirect back to /dashboard whenever I push /login in URL even if there's a token