# How to disable assess to login page once login is completed

Tags: node.js, vue.js

How can i block access to the pages once login has been completed in VueJS.
Also how can i display my server validation errors using bootstrap `invalid-feedback` class?

Please comment if you have any questions regarding my code or want me to clarify anything more in-depth.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="h-100 bg-plum-plate bg-animation">
      <div class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <b-col md="8" class="mx-auto app-login-box">
          <div class="app-logo-inverse mx-auto mb-3"/>
            <div class="modal-dialog w-100 mx-auto">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="h5 modal-title text-center">
                    <h4 class="mt-2">
                      <div>Welcome back,</div>
                      <span>Please sign in to your account below.</span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <b-form-group id="Admin Email" label-for="Admin Email">
                    <b-form-input 
                      id="Admin Email"
                      type="email"
                      required
                      placeholder="Enter email..."
                      v-model="email">
                    </b-form-input>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {{errorMsg}}
                    </div>
                   </b-form-group>
                   <b-form-group 
                     id="Admin Password"
                     label-for="Admin Password"
                   >
                     <b-form-input 
                       id="Admin password"
                       type="password"
                       required
                       placeholder="Enter password..."
                       v-model="password"
                     ></b-form-input>
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                       {{errorMsg}}
                     </div>
                   </b-form-group>
                   <b-form-checkbox name="check" id="exampleCheck">
                     Keep me logged in
                   </b-form-checkbox>
                   <div class="divider"/></div>
                   <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
                     <div class="float-left">
                       <a 
                         href="javascript:void(0);" 
                         class="btn-lg btn btn-link"
                       >
                       Recover  Password</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="float-right">
                       <b-button variant="primary" size="lg" @click="signin">
                         Login to Dashboard
                       </b-button>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="text-center text-white opacity-8 mt-3"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </b-col>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import Authentication from '../../services/authenticationService.js'
import {store} from '../../store.js'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      store: store.state.login,
      errorMsg: '',
      stored: store
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async signin () {
      try{
        const login = await Authentication.login({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        })
        var secured = login.data.token.split(' ')[1]
        sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', login.data.token)

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('jwt') != null || sessionStorage.getItem('jwt') == login.data.token)
        {
          this.stored.isLoggedIn()
          this.$router.push('/admin')
        } else {
          this.$router.push('/admin/login')
        } 
      }
      catch(err){
        if(err.response){
          this.errorMsg = err.response.data.message
        }else if(err.request){
          this.errorMsg = err.request
        }else{
          this.errorMsg = err.message
        }
        this.errorMsg = err;
      }
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either check in the [created hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), or check in the [beforeRouteEnter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) guard.

You could also [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400151/how-to-guard-both-login-or-login-and-dashboard-or-dashboard-in-vu/58410625#58410625) out for a third option which uses beforeEach

#### Login.vue - Using the created hook

```js
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    if(/* If logged in */){
      this.$router.push('/admin')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Using beforeRouteEnter

```js
<script>
import { store } from '../../store'
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    if(/* Check store if logged in */){
      next('/admin')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you it solve the problem, but if i type the login to the url it took me to the Login page, But once i refresh that is when it took me back to my dashboard, how can i resolve this